# In Git, how do you extract a project from a ".repo" directory so you can work on it?

Tags: git, github, repo

I obtained a source code archive that had all its contents - apparently a bunch of Git repositories - bundled into a single ".repo" folder. Now I'm familiar with a ".git" folder, of course, but I'd never seen a ".repo" folder before and I am not sure how to use it. Some digging revealed there's a separate program from Git called "repo", apparently a helper tool built on top of it used for bundling multiple Git repositories together. Currently, I have the ".repo" folder extracted into its own enclosing folder wherein it rests alone.

I downloaded the `repo` tool, but I am not sure how exactly to use it. In particular, what I want to do is to be able to access or "check out" a copy of one of the source trees inside the folder so I can then work on it normally, i.e. edit code, compile it and the like, just like when you clone a Git repository from the Internet and/or check a branch out from a repository. Documentation doesn't seem too helpful - it mostly seems to cover creating a repo bundle, not what you should do if you are given one and want to use it.

Is that possible? And if not, how is one "supposed" to use a `.repo` insofar as manipulating, compiling, etc. the code in it goes? Even worse, when trying to use some commands on the `repo` tool in the enclosing directory I get that various files aren't found, e.g. one of the contained projects is "u-boot" (the one I want), and I want to get the most recent commit stored the bundle, so I *guessed* I should try `repo checkout HEAD u-boot`

```
$ repo checkout HEAD u-boot
error: in `checkout HEAD u-boot`: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/xxxxx/Software/yyyyy/u-boot/.git/HEAD'
```

The .repo folder is located on `/home/xxxxx/Software/yyyyy/` (adulterated for privacy), i.e. that folder contains the `.repo` folder, and I am running `repo` from within it. Yet that spec in the error suggests for some reason `repo` is not even trying to go into the `.repo` directory like how Git would naturally look in a `.git`. Instead it's acting like the contents to be searched have somehow been extracted outside of it. Is that correct? How then do I get them out?

Obviously I am completely clueless how to use `repo` as I've never used it before and worse, the documentation does not tell you how to handle the use case where a `.repo` folder is *given* to you.

Comment: `repo` is from Google, not from the Git project. I have not actually used it, but the point of `repo` is to take a bunch of separate Git repositories and treat them as a single, well, bundle. To take a repository *out* of the bundle would be to defeat `repo`. That might well be exactly what you want, but it's probably not what repo will do without a lot of ... persuasion.  Look for debug style commands.

Comment: @torek : So how do you work with a repository in a .repo bundle, then, _without_ checking it out, i.e. how do you do coding on it like you would code on a clone of a Git repository, when someone else handed you a .repo folder?

Comment: My understanding—which is very vague since (I repeat) I have never actually *used* `repo`—is that you run some repo command to build a working tree. You then run `make` or whatever as needed *in* the working tree, make changes as desired, and then run various `repo` commands that in turn run multiple Git commands to commit changes into the various Git repositories via some repo-specific rule-sets that one would learn about when learning how to use `repo`. The goal of all this would be to *pretend* that there's a monorepo made up of all the individual repositories.

Comment: @torek: Right, but in this case we have been _given_ a ``.repo`` tree folder and want to get at the juicy bits inside (the code). That's the problem. All the stuff I read seems to be talking about _creating_ and _maintaining_ one, not what happens if one is dropped into your lap and you wanna start working with the code in it.

Answer (score 1):

The `repo` manifest (`default.xml`) should include [`element remote`](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/docs/manifest-format.md#Element-remote)

> One or more remote elements may be specified.
> Each remote element specifies a Git URL shared by one or more projects and (optionally) the Gerrit review server those projects upload changes through.

That means you can read the relevant Git URL for the project you want to work one, clone it and work on it using standard Git command, assuming you can push back to it (or you would need to fork it first).

Check if your `.repo` content includes a `default.xml` or a reference to the bare repository URL which includes said manifest.

Comment: It does not have a ``default.xml``. It _does_ have a ``manifest.xml``.

Comment: ADD: There is such a line in a file _included from_ ``manifest.xml``, it begins "``<default remote ...``".

Comment: But is that the same thing?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Not sure: does it refer to an URL you can access and read?

Comment: The line looks like ``<default remote="NAME" sync-j="4" dest-branch="XXXX" revision="YYYY"/>`` where both XXXX and YYYY refer to non-absolute path specs that I do have (in more than one place, actually, so I'm not sure which ones this command references) as part of the ``.repo`` local directory. They are not internet URLs, though.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer OK. I am not familiar enough with the `repo` tool, but the idea remains to explorer those paths and see if there is any reference to the original remote repositories URLs

Comment: The point of the ".repo" folder seems to be that it has _local_ copies of the underlying Git repositories, and I want to get at those. Do you know who would be likely to know more about this tool?